# How to write a formula that would work in different rows?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a Google spreadsheet where I want the sum of the values in the row to appear in the AH cell of that row. 
The row would be populated with letters like L or X and I'm using COUNTIF to give value to the alphabet characters.
For example,

`=COUNTIF(C4:AG4,"X")*9 + COUNTIF(C4:AG4,"L")*12`

How can I write the range such that it looks at cells C through AG from the same row the formula is in rather than change it for every row?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the formula, if you write that formula in one cell and then you drag the little square at the bottom right of the cell, excel will automatically change the row number

Answer (score 0):

Just copy downwards:

[image]

As you see, the row index changed to ***5*** automatically.